# php datetime is thinking the day part is the month

Tags: php, datetime

I am inputting a date into datetime as such:

```
date('Y-m-d',strtotime('07/04/18'))
```

But it thinks the 04 is the day and 07 is the month. I will have no control of the date input but it will always be day/month/year  when in the above mentioned format. Is there a way to tell date class that the month and day are the other way around?

Comment: When strtotime encounters `/` as a separator, it assumes US `m/d/Y` format; if it encounters `-` or `.` as a separator, it assumes `d-m-Y` format; [as explained in the PHP Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

Comment: is there a way to tell it that it wont be in US format?

Comment: Yes there is.... use [DateTime objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), and [createFromFormat()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: but doesn't this then assume that every date string i enter will be in the format DD/MM/YY, what about when i enter something like DD/MM/YYYY or DD/M/YYYY and so on. as i will never know what format it is in.

Comment: If you never know what format it is, then you have a problem; you should always know what format you're receiving data in.... you shouldn't allow any format and hope that code can resolve any ambiguities; if you can't tell me whether `4/6/2017` is 4th June or 6th April, then how can you expect a computer program to magically guess correctly every time?

Comment: i can't be 100% of the format because i am replying on a 3rd party to supply it. but i know they will always give the day first.

Comment: If the basis is always a d/m/Y style format (but sometimes with somethimes without leading zeroes for month or day), then createFromFormat() with a format mask of `d/m/Y` will parse th format successfully; 2- or 4-digit year is strict though